# Edimax EW-7811UN Debian

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, firmware

I just installed Debian with xfce and am loving it except my wifi adapter doesn't work. As mentioned in the description, it is an Edimax EW-7811UN. My laptop is Sony Vaio VGN-NR260E running Debian Jessie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Debian wiki page for the rtl819x set of drivers](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x), this is supported by the `rtl8192cu` module.

You probably already have this module installed (it's installed by default in the Debian kernel), but it requires non-free firmware to operate. You can install the required non-free firmware by installing the `firmware-realtek` package.

You'll need to have non-free sources enabled first if you don't have them enabled already, instructions to do that are [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/q/240920/95016). After doing that, you can use `apt-get` as root to install the package:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-realtek
```

After doing this you may need to disable and reenable your wireless device for the driver to go through the initialisation procedure again and find the non-free firmware you installed.

Answer (score 3):

> ### Installation
>
> Ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms
> ```
>
> Clone this repository:
>
> ```
> git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
> ```
>
> Set it up as a DKMS module:
>
> ```
> sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
> ```
>
> Build and install it (this version number may change, it is .10 as of october 19 2015
>
> ```
> sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10
> ```
>
> Refresh the module list:
>
> ```
> sudo depmod -a
> ```
>
> Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:
>
> ```
> sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
> ```
>
> And reboot. You're done.